# Stuck using DATE_SUB (sorting last week records)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch records from a database based on time, specifically last week and last month, but I'm stuck somewhere. These are the MySQL queries that I used for fetching last week's info:

```
"SELECT *FROM posts WHERE date BETWEEN DATE SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND CURDATE()"

"SELECT *FROM posts WHERE date BETWEEN DATE SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATE SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 13 DAY) "

"SELECT *FROM posts WHERE date <= DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , 8 DAY)"
```

I also did this:

```
$lastweek = time() - (7*24*60*60);
```

With the following query:

```
"SELECT *FROM posts WHERE date <= '$lastweek' "
```

But it is not working the way it should. For example, if there is a date like `2014-07-26` in the database, and another date like `2013-07-26`, it is fetching both whereas it should only fetch `2014-07-26`.

I'm using the MySQL `CURDATE()` function to insert into the database.

Comment: your first two queries doesn't have the correct function, should be `between date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 week) and curdate()` (missing underscore) on `date_sub()` or probably a typo

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare dates that are in unix timestamp format with sql format. You need to convert the values :

SELECT *FROM posts WHERE date <= from_unixtime($lastweek)

Comment: @ charlie... yea, it was a typo.

@ Meyer... from_unixtime display an undefined function error.

Please what do you think I should do?

Comment: Did you misspell it? Look at the manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime